# Directly working with data from different platform without having to download it in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, global

Is it possible to import and work with data that is not hosted in Google Earth Engine without having to download it?

I am working with a publicly available Global Man-made Impervious Surface (GMIS) Dataset From Landsat, v1 that is available on NASA website but my points of interest are distributed globally. I am not able to down a global or regional map so I have to download country by country or supply small polygons which is quite tedious.

Comment: Are you trying to work with this data in Google Earth Engine?  If not, then I think your tag for that should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be a suitable alternative dataset but the Global Impervious Surface Area (GISA) dataset is available through the Google Earth Engine Community Catalog. This means the data has already been stored on Google's servers as a user asset so you should be able to access it as you would any other user asset.

The link to the dataset is [here](https://gee-community-catalog.org/projects/gisa/)

Here's the import snippet:

```
var gisa = ee.ImageCollection("projects/sat-io/open-datasets/GISA_1972_2019");
```

If that's not quite what you're looking for I think the best way to go about it would just be to download the tiles that intersect your sample points from NASA. Although this could still be a large number of tiles. I'm not aware of any way to access external datasets from within the Earth Engine environment.